# Variable Length Arrays in C++14?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2015, c99, variable-length-array

[n3639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html) proposed the adoption of [c99](/questions/tagged/c99)'s [variable-length-array](/questions/tagged/variable-length-array)s into C++14 (at least for the first dimension.)

But the [latest I've been able to find](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4200#recs.removed) lists n3639 as:

> Features in the first CD of C++14, subsequently removed to a Technical Specification

Did this ever make it into a Technical Specification, or was it lost in the hand off?

The reason for my question is, I've noticed this code:

```
void f(size_t n) {
    int a[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        a[i] = 2 * i;
    sort(a, a + n);
}
```

This fails to build in Visual Studio 2015 and in gcc (when the "-pedantic" flag is used.)

<strike>[Works fine](http://ideone.com/oXFiF6) under gcc5.1, but still [fails to build](http://rextester.com/FVUF49304) under Visual Studio 2015.</strike>

Is this just gcc incorrectly supporting c99's Variable Length Arrays in C++14 or did this somehow make it into C++14 and Visual Studio 2015 failed to pick it up?

**EDIT:** It looks like gcc has removed support in gcc6.2: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/303ae1970fa3f5d2

Comment: It has always been a GCC extension since C++03 or earlier.

Comment: GCC supports this as an extension. Turn on your warning flags. Or better yet, don't use VLA's in C++.

Comment: [It was removed from the standard](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yup I've got a link from http://www.open-std.org stating that in the question. The question is why it still works by default in gcc?

Comment: It compiles by default because gcc compiles gnuc++ programs and not c++ programs by default.

Comment: @JonathanMee: A lot of things work by default in GCC which are not required by the standard.  If you don't like it, say `-std=c++14 -pedantic` or so.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Ah, you're right. I can't see my command line on http://ideone.org but it must not have the "-pedantic" flag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, [n3639](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html) was looking to put in place Arrays with Runtime Bound (ARB) not Variable Length Arrays (VLA). ARBs would support a subset of VLAs which excluded:

> - multidimensional arrays, where other than the top level has a runtime bound (in analogy, array-new doesn't support that either)
> - modifications to the function declarator syntax
> - `sizeof(a)` being a runtime-evaluated expression returning the size of `a`
> - `typedef int a[n];` evaluating `n` and passing that through the `typedef`

In February of 2014 in Issaquah, Washington, at the standard committee [unanimously voted](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3901.pdf) to form the Array Extensions Technical Specification from [n3820](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3820.html), it's initial revision originated from n3639 and [the proposal of Dynarrays](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3662.html).

In May 2014 [n4043](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4043.html) and [n4050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4050.html) attempted to address some "semi-editorial issues" in the Dynarray and ARB sections of the Array Extension Technical Specification, respectively.

But [the standard committee's October 24 2014 teleconference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4250.html) cited huge disagreement on the language facilities, implementation possibilities, and desire for Array Extensions Technical Specification, ultimately describing it as in a state of limbo.

[The standard committee's May 2015 meeting in Lenexa, Kansas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4490.html) went on to give the directional guidance that the Array Extensions Technical Specification would not be accepted in it's current form, and recommended:

> Stripping the TS of its current contents, and waiting for a workable proposal to come along<sup>[[1]](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-lenexa-may-2015/)</sup>

Ultimately [the standard committee's March 2016 meeting in Jacksonville, Florida](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4586.pdf) moved to close the Array Extensions Technical Specification at the confirmation that some array-related proposals are targeting the Library Fundamentals Technical Specification instead. There was a [unanimous vote to do so](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp%2Fexperimental&diff=83587&oldid=83552) with 8 strongly in favor, 5 in favor, and 6 abstaining.

Incidentally the only array related work going into the Library Fundamentals Technical Specification is the allowance of run-time creation of an `array` via [`make_array`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4600.html#container.array). [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup), the creator of C++, [waxed eloquent on the topic](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3810.pdf):

> We need arrays with run-time-specified bounds and safer access to such storage “yesterday”

Sadly, for Dr. Stroustrup, us, and the C++ community as a whole, there are no future plans to resurrect ARBs/VLAs with C++ in the simple c99 VLA form.

Comment: @陳力 Thanks, I should do some research. I'm certain that with Dr. Stroustrup's backing we've got another ARB/VLA proposal in the works, but I just haven't had time to research it.