# C Unicode: How do I apply C11 standard amendment DR488 fix to C11 standard function c16rtomb()?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, c11

## Question:

As mentioned in the C reference page for the function, `c16rtomb`, from [CPPReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/c16rtomb), under the **Notes** section:

> In C11 as published, unlike `mbrtoc16`, which converts variable-width multibyte (such as UTF-8) to variable-width 16-bit (such as UTF-16) encoding, this function can only convert single-unit 16-bit encoding, meaning it cannot convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 despite that being the original intent of this function. This was corrected by the post-C11 defect report [DR488](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/summary.htm#dr_488).

And below this passage, the C reference page provided an example source code with the following sentence above it:

> **Note:** this example assumes the fix for the defect report 488 is applied.

That phrase implied there is a way to take DR488 and somehow "apply" the fix to the C11 standard function, `c16rtomb`.

I would like to know how to apply the fix for GCC. Because it seems to me the fix was already applied to Visual Studio 2017 Visual C++, as of v141.

The behavior seen in GCC, when debugging the code in GDB, is consistent with what was found in DR488, as follows:

> Section 7.28.1 describes the function c16rtomb(). In particular, it states "When c16 is not a valid wide character, an encoding error occurs". "wide character" is defined in section 3.7.3 as "value representable by an object of type wchar_t, capable of representing any character in the current locale". **This wording seems to imply that, e.g. for the common cases (e.g, an implementation that defines __STDC_UTF_16__ and a program that uses an UTF-8 locale), c16rtomb() will return -1 when it encounters a character that is encoded as multiple char16_t (for UTF-16 a wide character can be encoded as a surrogate pair consisting of two char16_t).** In particular, c16rtomb() will not be able to process strings generated by mbrtoc16().

The boldfaced text is the behavior described.

## Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uchar.h>

#define __STD_UTF_16__

int main() {
    char16_t* ptr_string = (char16_t*) u"我是誰";

    //C++ disallows variable-length arrays. 
    //GCC uses GNUC++, which has a C++ extension for variable length arrays.
    //It is not a truly standard feature in C++ pedantic mode at all.
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633344/variable-length-arrays-in-c14
    char buffer[64];
    char* bufferOut = buffer;

    //Must zero this object before attempting to use mbstate_t at all.
    mbstate_t multiByteState = {};

    //c16 = 16-bit Characters or char16_t typed characters
    //r = representation
    //tomb = to Multi-Byte Strings
    while (*ptr_string) {
        char16_t character = *ptr_string;
        size_t size = c16rtomb(bufferOut, character, &multiByteState);
        if (size == (size_t) -1)
            break;
        bufferOut += size;
        ptr_string++;
    }

    size_t bufferOutSize = bufferOut - buffer;
    printf("Size: %zu - ", bufferOutSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferOutSize; i++) {
        printf("%#x ", +(unsigned char) buffer[i]);
    }

    //This statement is used to set a breakpoint. It does not do anything else.
    int debug = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

## Output from Visual Studio:

```
Size: 9 - 0xe6 0x88 0x91 0xe6 0x98 0xaf 0xe8 0xaa 0xb0
```

## Output from GCC:

```
Size: 0 -
```

Comment: There is certainly a way to fix standard library functions: download the source code for the standard library, change the code, build it and install it. DR488 doesn't have a patch, it's only a patch for the wording. Someone has to translate the words into code.

Comment: @immibis Oh, so that's what it means. I'll look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux you should be able to fix this with a call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");`

Example on [ideone](https://ideone.com/q5Xpni)

This function will do the following, as stated in [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634420.aspx):

> Convert a UTF-16 wide character into a multibyte character in the ***current locale***.

The POSIX documentation is similar. `__STD_UTF_16__` doesn't seem to have an effect in either compiler. It's supposed to specify the encoding for the source, which should be UTF16. It doesn't specify the encoding for destination.

*It's Windows documentation which seems more inconsistent, because it seems to imply that `setlocale` is necessary or converting to ANSI code page is an option*

Comment: Thank you! I thought I really have to learn how to compile and build gcc with modifications to match the DR488, as there was no good answers available until now.